# Alerts when navigating away from a web page

Tags: javascript, browser, google-docs, alerts

When I try to close my Google docs tab with unsaved changes, this is what I get in my browser (FF 3.5).

> Are you sure you want to navigate away
>   from this page?
>
> You have unsaved changes in this
>   document. Click Cancel now, then
>   'Save' to save them. Click OK now to
>   discard them.
>
> Press OK to continue, or Cancel to
>   stay on the current page.

My question is whether such alerts are part of the web app (gdocs for eg.) or are they given out by the browser? If latter, how is this done?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

By the browser.  It's the `beforeunload` event handler that returns the customized text of the dialog, which is only the middle of the three paragraphs - the other two paragraphs as well as the text of the buttons cannot be customized or otherwise changed.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){ return 'Testing...' }

// OR

var unloadListener = function(){ return 'Testing...' };
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', unloadListener);
```

Will yield a dialog that says

```
Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?

Testing...

Press OK to continue, or Cancel to stay on the current page.
```

You can nullify this by setting the handler to null

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;

// OR

window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', unloadListener);
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. I have looked into how the modern browsers behave wrt the onbeforeunload event and posted my findings. Please add on any other intricate details that you know.

Comment: Hi Peter, is there no way we can tap into the event to yield a custom alert which provides the same functionality as the native window alert?

Comment: Not that I know of, no.

Comment: @PeterBailey I suggest you updating your answer and use more modern `addEventListener` instead of `onbeforeunload`. Also, the event name is `beforeunload`, not `onbeforeunload`.

Comment: @MichałPerłakowski, it seems that another answer is warranted (with your suggestions).

Answer (score -16):

The alerts are part of the web application. View the source code and look at the javascript.

Comment: I cannot see it in Google Docs source, at least.

Comment: It's likely buried in some obscure JavaScript file. Google uses scripts that make their JavaScript files essentially unreadable to a human.

Comment: before using alert, an event has to identified first. which "onBeforeUnload"