# Prompting and preventing user from navigating away/closing a page

Tags: javascript

As per how StackOverflow does it when you are adding a question or replying to a question;

I'd like to prompt the user with a;

```
"Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page"
"Press OK to continue or Cancel to stay on this page"
```

I've tried a couple of js snippets i've found on ze internet, but nothing quite cuts the mustard.

Comment: More detail on the mustard please.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289234/alerts-when-navigating-away-from-a-web-page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to implement [window.onbeforeunload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907%28VS.85%29.aspx) and return your message from it as a string:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (theUserHasStartedEditing) {
        return "You have started writing or editing a post."
    }
}
```

There's an online demo here: https://web.archive.org/web/20210619174356/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/OnBeforeUnloadDemo2.htm