# IE11's F12 developer tools lack option to keep console on navigation

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Trying to debug a problem that's IE-11 specific, I would like to see the console messages logged when a certain control is clicked. But the control refreshes the page, which makes F12 tools automatically clear the console, so whatever is logged just before that, I don't get to see!

Past versions of IE had an option to keep the console contents on navigation. Is this option available in IE11? If so, where is it? If not, is there some other way to view the console that doesn't immediately discard the message I want to see?

Answer (score 6):

In with the latest F12 update to IE11 (that came as part of the Win8.1 Update) there is now a button to disable "Clear on Navigate"

[image]

Additionally, you can enable IE to record messages in the Console at all times instead of only when the Console is open.

For all the changes to the IE11 F12 dev tools see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2929437

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this and I didn't find a *good* solution, but I found a hacked one that worked well enough for me to debug.

Use window.onbeforeunload to pop up a window so you can at least see the values before they are purged.

See: [Prompting and preventing user from navigating away/closing a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638975/prompting-and-preventing-user-from-navigating-away-closing-a-page)