# onbeforeunload not working - tried javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript

**This is not a duplicate.** I have read through several other Stack posts and have attempted various approaches at this (both pure javascript and jquery), including these:

[Why is jQuery onbeforeunload not working in Chrome and Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22776544/why-is-jquery-onbeforeunload-not-working-in-chrome-and-firefox)

[Prompting and preventing user from navigating away/closing a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638975/prompting-and-preventing-user-from-navigating-away-closing-a-page)

I have implemented a bare-bones simple approach at prompting the user with a messagebox but it never works. Clicking the "go to google" link ought to prompt the box, but it doesn't. Here is my full code:

```
<html>
<head>

<script>

    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    function confirmExit()
    {
        return "You have attempted to leave this page.";
    }

</script>

</head>

<body>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <a href="https://www.google.com/">go to google</a>

</body>
</html>
```

I have also tried the jquery approach. I am using Chrome 47.0.2526.106 m. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: code you posted works for me in same version of Chrome, maybe something in settings??

Comment: I have the same version of Chrome than you (but on Mac) and it seems to work all right, but the dialog is prompted twice :-/

Comment: the above code only works for me if I click refresh. If I click another link on the page it doesn't provide the prompt.