# How to show confirm box like StackOverflow's confirmation box?

Tags: javascript, confirmation

Ask a question, and while editing the body of your question, click on some link on the page. StackOverflow's script knows that you are not finished yet, and warns you about loosing your unsaved data. However, it's confirmation box is not a jQuery plugin, or anything like that. It seems that its confirmation box is browser-specific box, something like JavaScript's `confirm` box. To prove it, simply check it in many browsers and you see different UI styles.

How they've done it? Which JavaScript command?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alerts when navigating away from a web page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289234/alerts-when-navigating-away-from-a-web-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onbeforeunload` Javascript event is what you're looking for.

Comment: His question is a duplicate, I will remove my answer when this question is closed.

Comment: @Martin I already added the short answer when James marked it as a duplicate. So I did not write the longer version, as I normally do.

Answer (score 1):

Trying setting a **global flag** to know when the page is "**editing**" and then use the onbeforeunload event

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){ return globalEditingFlag ? 'You are editing': null }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this : 
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp

The section about the confirm box