# ASP.Net check box inside update panel

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, webforms

I have have an asp.net check box with autopostback set to true inside an update panel. When I check the check box it shows the other controls that I want to show. When I un-check the check box a value in the database is updated. This is all working fine.

If I want to move to another page after un-checking the check box a dialog which is asking whether I want to stay on this page or leave the page is displayed. How can I stop that dialog box from appearing?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upOnProbation" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Text="On Probation" ID="chkOnProbation" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="AutoID" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="plcProbabtionDates" Visible="false">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Start date
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <ComponentArt:Calendar runat="server" ID="dtStart" ControlType="Picker" PickerFormat="Short">
                                </ComponentArt:Calendar>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                End date
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <ComponentArt:Calendar runat="server" ID="dtEnd" ControlType="Picker" PickerFormat="Short">
                                </ComponentArt:Calendar>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                         <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSave" Text="Save" CssClass="btn" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </asp:PlaceHolder>                   
                </table>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>

    </asp:UpdatePanel>




Protected Sub chkOnProbation_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkOnProbation.CheckedChanged
        If chkOnProbation.Checked Then
            plcProbabtionDates.Visible = True
            dtStart.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now
            dtEnd.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6)
        Else
            plcProbabtionDates.Visible = False
            objCompany.On_Probation = False
            objCompany.Save(UserStaffID)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289234/alerts-when-navigating-away-from-a-web-page) for an explanation as to why this happens.

basically when you have a form on a web page the browser will fire an `onbeeforeunload` event for you to ensure that unsaved changes are accounted for.

The answer to the previous question states that you can avoid this by setting the handler to `null`

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```