# Jquery Confirm function in anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Normally when click anchor tag it redirects to some url which is given inside the "href" attribute. Is there is any possiblity here for confirmation. When we click anchor tag it shows confirmation "Are you sure want to continue" if we clicked "yes" it gets redirect to that url which is given inside "href". if we click "no" it remains in same page. Please share any ideas you might have.

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Nqzek/

Comment: Sure it is possible! What have you tried?

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289234/alerts-when-navigating-away-from-a-web-page

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try this

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" >click here</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    return confirm('Are you sure want to continue?');
});
```

Therefore if the user click's cancel you return `false` and the link won't send you anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
<a href="www.anysite.com" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Any site</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using below html link and jquery code. Don't forget to include Jquery library from http://jquery.com.

```
<a href="go.html?id=22" class="confirm">Go>></a>

<!-- Include jQuery - see http://jquery.com -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.confirm').on('click', function () {
        return confirm('Are you sure want to continue?');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes

```
$('a').click(function(){
    return confirm('do you want to proceed')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').click(function(){return confirm('sure?')})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a stylish box, jQuery has a Dialog Widget.
This is the link to the widget's API:
[Dialog Widget - Open content in an interactive overlay.](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/)

I would use it as part of my confirm().

Comment: Here is a nice tutorial on jQuery-style Dialog Boxes:
http://savage.net.au/jQuery-tutorials/html/dialog.boxes.html